# How to localize decimal separator in redux-form number field?

Tags: redux, redux-form, number-formatting

Is there a way to localize the delimiter separator in redux-form Field type='number' so that in all major browsers in German localization in would be `','`, and in English - `'.'`. I need to be able to set the localization from state, and it should correctly apply.

Currently browsers ignore my formatting and use separators as they want. No way to change it dynamically.